# ftp_put is corrupting my movies after transfer, is it wrong?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a bunch of movies that I'm trying to transfer from my CentOS server onto my Windows PC. But when I run them through this script they end up being corrupt. Is there something wrong with the script?

Thanks

```
$allFiles = glob("/var/www/html/ftp_pending/*");

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

foreach($allFiles as $singleFile)
{
    // check if a file exist
    $path = "/"; //the path where the file is located

    $file = substr( $singleFile, strrpos( $singleFile, '/' )+1 );

    $check_file_exist = $path.$file; //combine string for easy use

    // Returns an array of filenames from the specified directory on success or
    // FALSE on error. 
    $contents_on_server = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path); 

    // Test if file is in the ftp_nlist array
    if (in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server)) 
    {
        echo "$file is already on FTP Server, no need to re-upload <br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $localfile = '/var/www/html/'.$file.'';
        $remote_file = $file;
        
        // upload a file
        if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $localfile, FTP_ASCII))
        {
             echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
        }
        else
        {
             echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
        }
    };

}
        
// remember to always close your ftp connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to upload something other than a text-based file while using

```
(ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $localfile, FTP_ASCII))
```

You should be using `FTP_BINARY` instead of `FTP_ASCII` since movies (and images) are binary files.